# Unable to upgrade Perl's CPAN on OS X

Tags: macos, perl, cpan

I'm unable to upgrade [CPAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPAN) by using `cpan` and typing install CPAN on [Mac OS X v10.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Yosemite) (Yosemite).

This is the error I'm receiving:

```
All tests successful.
Files=30, Tests=438,  8 wallclock secs ( 0.13 usr  0.05 sys +  6.80 cusr  1.34 csys =  8.32 CPU)
Result: PASS
  ANDK/CPAN-2.10.tar.gz
Tests succeeded but one dependency not OK (File::HomeDir)
  ANDK/CPAN-2.10.tar.gz
  [dependencies] -- NA
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Failed during this command:
 ADAMK/Test-Script-1.07.tar.gz                : make_test NO 2 dependencies missing (Probe::Perl,IPC::Run3); additionally test harness failed
 ADAMK/File-Which-1.09.tar.gz                 : make_test NO one dependency not OK (Test::Script); additionally test harness failed
 ADAMK/File-HomeDir-1.00.tar.gz               : make_test NO 2 dependencies missing (Mac::SystemDirectory,File::Which); additionally test harness failed
 ANDK/CPAN-2.10.tar.gz                        : make_test NO one dependency not OK (File::HomeDir)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling CPAN, then reinstalling it.

Comment: I've done that, and i'm still getting an issue stating that it cannot complete the install due to missing dependencies, but when i attempt to install the dependencies i still get the same error

Comment: The only other suggestion I have for you is that you try deleting everything related to CPAN, then reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

It says you need to install it with force.
I don't know how the OSX environment does this, but in linuxland we use sudo.

Try installing it from command line (terminal) with the sudo command.